# Getting a product price from an ecommerce site using file get content

Tags: php, file-get-contents, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to get a product price using php and file_get_contents function. Here is my code. It is loading the whole page however I just need the price from this page. Can someone please help? Thanks

```
<?php
$homepage = file_get_contents('https://www.snapdeal.com/product/bhawna-collection-loard-shiv-trishul/672311651336');
echo $homepage;
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PHP Simple HTML DOM parser](https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/manual.htm) is a godsend for this kind of thing

Get the [code here](https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/index.htm)

Just include it on your php

```
require_once('./path/to/SimpleHtmlDom.php');
// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('https://www.snapdeal.com/product/bhawna-collection-loard-shiv-trishul/672311651336');

// Find all images
$price = $html->find('.pdp-final-price .payBlkBig', 0)->plaintext;
```

More about [this awesome tool](https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/manual.htm)

Answer (score 1):

With use standarts functions

```
 <?php
    
    $homepage = file_get_contents('https://www.snapdeal.com/product/bhawna-collection-loard-shiv-trishul/672311651336');
    $search = '<span class="payBlkBig"  itemprop="price">';
    $subStrPos = strpos($homepage, $substring) + strlen($search);
    $subStr = substr($string, $subStrPos);
    $price = substr($subStr, 0, strpos($subs, '</span>'));
    
    echo $price;
```

Comment: According to the docs of `strpos()`: `Warning: This function may return Boolean false, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to false.`